# checkbox dropdown for multiple selection seperated by ;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a multiple selection checkbox from a dropdown and get the chosen results concatenated by `;`.

my code looks like that:

```js
var myobject = {
    ValueA : 'Text A',
    ValueB : 'Text B',
    ValueC : 'Text C',
    ValueD : 'Text D',
    ValueE : 'Text E',
    ValueF : 'Text F'
};
var select = document.getElementById("rec_mode");
for(index in myobject) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
}
```

```html
<select id="rec_mode">        
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the function `selectedValue()`, which is fired when the select change its value. Also, for multiple values you must to add `multiple` attribute to the select tag.

```js
var myobject = {
    ValueA : 'Text A',
    ValueB : 'Text B',
    ValueC : 'Text C',
    ValueD : 'Text D',
    ValueE : 'Text E',
    ValueF : 'Text F'
};
var select = document.getElementById("rec_mode");
for(index in myobject) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
}

function selectedValue() {
  var selectChilds = document.getElementById("rec_mode").childNodes;
  var selectedValues = "";
  
  for(var i = 0; i < selectChilds.length; i++){
    if(selectChilds[i].selected){
      selectedValues += selectChilds[i].value + ";";
    }
  }
  
  alert(selectedValues.substring(0, selectedValues.length -1));
}
```

```html
<select id="rec_mode" multiple onchange="selectedValue()">        
</select>
```

## EDIT

If you wish to write the code with `checkbox` tags, follow this snippet.

```js
var myobject = {
    ValueA : 'Text A',
    ValueB : 'Text B',
    ValueC : 'Text C',
    ValueD : 'Text D',
    ValueE : 'Text E',
    ValueF : 'Text F'
};
var chbxs = document.getElementById("rec_mode");
for(index in myobject) {
    chbxs.innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" value="' + index + '" /> ' + myobject[index] + '<br />'
}

function selectedValue() {
  var selectChilds = document.getElementById("rec_mode").childNodes;
  var selectedValues = "";
  
  for(var i = 0; i < selectChilds.length; i++){
    if(selectChilds[i].checked){
      selectedValues += selectChilds[i].value + ";";
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = selectedValues.substring(0, selectedValues.length -1);
}
```

```html
<div id="rec_mode" onchange="selectedValue()">        
  
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply ! could you assist with how to add checkbox aside the options?

Comment: You'r welcome. Adding checkbox aside the options tags, will modify the HTML structure, because you have to remove the `select / option` tag, and use `checkbox` tags. With only HTML you can't add `checkbox` aside an `option` inside a `select`. So, if you wish a new solution with these inconveniences, I'll assist you on that way.

Comment: Hi Yulio, I would appreciate if you could assist that way

Comment: Hi @johnbrandes, review the new section of the answer, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye it is half answer but it can help you :)

```js
 var myobject = {
  ValueA : 'Text A',
  ValueB : 'Text B',
  ValueC : 'Text C',
  ValueD : 'Text D',
  ValueE : 'Text E',
  ValueF : 'Text F'
};
  
$(document).ready(function() {
  for(index in myobject) {
    var temp ="<li><input type='checkbox' value='"+index+"' />"+index+"</li>"
    document.getElementById("listOfCheckbox").innerHTML +=temp;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="mutliSelect">
      <ul id="listOfCheckbox"></ul>
</div>
```